How to calculate the matrix representation of a quadratic form?
I'm working on a problem involving quadratic forms and I need some help verifying my calculations. Here is the problem:

I'm given a quadratic form ( q(x, y, z) = x^2 + 2yz ).

The basis ( B ) for ( {R}^3 ) is given by the vectors:
B = { \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}

I need to find the matrix representation ([q]_B) of the quadratic form ( q ) with respect to the basis ( B ).


Using the given information, I have the following evaluations of ( q ):
[
q(1,0,0) = 1, q(0,1,1) = 2, q(0, -0.5, 0.5) = -0.5
]
Could someone guide me on how to calculate ([q]_B) and verify if it matches the given matrix:

[q]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -0.5 \end{pmatrix}
Any detailed explanation or steps would be greatly appreciated!

take a look to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98714/generalization-of-the-polarisation-formula-for-symmetric-bilinear-forms-to-symme

or this easier https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form#Examples

Let $g$ be the symmetric bilinear form associated to $q$ and let $G$ be the matrix of $g$ with respect to the standard basis. If $G’$ is the matrix of $g$ with respect to $B$, then $G$ and $G’$ are congruent. This means that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $G’ = P^{t}GP$. P is indeed the change of basis matrix from $B$ to the standard basis.

Sorry I didn't get that... you just said there is P this doesn't answer my question on how o find that P etc...

It sure does, because $P$ is the change of basis matrix. It is an analogous situation as when you have different basis representing the same linear operator, your new matrix is always related to the existing one by the equation $P^{-1}AP$ where $P$ is the change of basis matrix.
